# global variables remain undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

After setting value for my global variables, they have their value only inside the function scope the value was set in

I have 2 different buttons, that call functions joinChat() and log(). If I click the button that calls joinChat() function then it prints the expected result, but if I click the button, that calls the log() function, then it prints both variables as undefined, but this is unexpected, because they should have gotten their value before (when I clicked joinChat())

```
chat: ChatSession;
   participant: Person;


  log(){
    console.log(this.chat)
    console.log(this.participant);
  }

  joinChat(room: string, participantName: string) {
      this.chat = new ChatSession(room);
      this.participant = new Person(participantName);
      console.log(this.chat);
      console.log(this.participant)
}
```

Expected output would be:
If i click joinChat() button first, then clicking log() button would print the same values as in joinChat() method, not undefined

Comment: Those are not global variables. Thse are instance properties of your class. You probably set th properties of one instanceof the class, and display the properties of another instance. But that's pure conjecture, because you didn't post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. Post one.

Comment: Can you share a simple stackbiltz for this

Comment: As we don't know where the log function is being called from, it would be hard to tell you what is the problem. @JBNizet comment is one option, while another option can be the function binding is incorrect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Is it a class ? Can you share with us the full source code

Comment: Thank you for the replies and sorry for not providing more context. Apparently I had to make chat and participant variables static and few other modifications to get the desired result.